# Return row ID from MySQL insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, mysql-insert-id

I have this function inside a functions file. I call it using this (from another file that calls includes the functions file):       newBorrow_request($newBorrowRequest); ($newBorrowRequest) is an array of fields.

The function inserts data into the database, and it works fine.

The question: How can i return the ID field that it inserts into? I need the value in the same file where the function is called, can someone give me code for the function & code of how to call it in another file to get the ID?

Thanks

```
function newBorrow_request($newBorrowRequest) {
array_walk($newBorrowRequest, 'array_sanitise');

$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($newBorrowRequest)) . '`';
$data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $newBorrowRequest) . '\'';

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `borrowRequest` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
if (!$query) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}

}
```

Comment: http://php.net/mysql_insert_id - but do note the big red warning box about that function (and all the mysql_* functions)

Comment: @andrewsi I'v seen this... but if I add $id = mysql_insert_id(); and then return $id; how can I get that returned value from the other file? Because if i call the function again is says that it cannot query (obviously because when I call it it wants to insert to the database again)

Comment: In that case, you just need to return `$id` from this function.

Comment: @andrewsi but how do I call that in the other file? Because I call this newBorrow_request($newBorrowRequest); then it writes to database, then I show a success message & need the ID, so if i call newBorrow_request(); that it thinks I'm trying to do a new query and obviously doesn't work because I'm not sending the fields through

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't just about how to get the last insert id, it's also about how to get it outside of the function.

It needs to be returned by the function.

```
function newBorrow_request($newBorrowRequest){
    // your procedure
    return mysql_insert_id();
}
```

When you call the function, the return sets the variable

```
$last_insert_id=newBorrow_request($some_data);
```

which you can use

```
echo $last_insert_id;
```

*NB. Please use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql*

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with < 5.5.0:
http://php.net/mysql_insert_id

Preferable:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use this line of code:

```
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

But be aware this function is deprecated as of php 5.5.0. 
If you look at php.net/mysql_insert_id a few suggestions are given for replacements.